# Trouble constructing function to visualize Alphafold2 predictions

Tags: python, data-visualization

I'm trying to use the following script (which is largely based off of this wonderful Colab here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/sokrypton/ColabFold/blob/main/AlphaFold2.ipynb#scrollTo=UGUBLzB3C6WN) to visualize the predicted folding of an amino acid sequence. I'm having trouble configuring the script in a way that will run, and for largely-institutional reasons, I'm not able to freely run-and-debug the script on my data, and can really only use it for the final runs. The error message I'm receiving right now (in reference to the `show_pdb()` third-to-last line) is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue, and possibly others that aren't yet apparent to me? I've included the hashed-out parts for context, if it's necessary or desired, but the main part I'd like help with is the construction of the `show_pdb()` function.

```
import os
import re
import glob

#@title Display 3D structure {run: "auto"}
model_num = 1 #@param ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] {type:"raw"}
color = "lDDT" #@param ["chain", "lDDT", "rainbow"]
show_sidechains = False #@param {type:"boolean"}
show_mainchains = False #@param {type:"boolean"}

def get_filepaths(root_path: str, file_regex: str):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(root_path, file_regex))

rootdir = '/projects/p31492/long_alphafold/alphafold__long_sequence_file'
regex = '.pdb'
pdb_files = get_filepaths(rootdir, regex)

def show_pdb(model_num=1, show_sidechains=False, show_mainchains=False, color="lDDT"):
    for file in pdb_files:      
        view = py3Dmol.view(js='https://3dmol.org/build/3Dmol.js',)
        view.addModel(open(file,'r').read(),'pdb')

        if color == "lDDT":
            view.setStyle({'cartoon': {'colorscheme': {'prop':'b','gradient': 'roygb','min':50,'max':90}}})
        elif color == "rainbow":
            view.setStyle({'cartoon': {'color':'spectrum'}})
        elif color == "chain":
            for n,chain,color in zip(range(homooligomer),list("ABCDEFGH"),
                             ["lime","cyan","magenta","yellow","salmon","white","blue","orange"]):
                view.setStyle({'chain':chain},{'cartoon': {'color':color}})
        if show_sidechains:
            BB = ['C','O','N']
            view.addStyle({'and':[{'resn':["GLY","PRO"],'invert':True},{'atom':BB,'invert':True}]},
                                {'stick':{'colorscheme':f"WhiteCarbon",'radius':0.3}})
            view.addStyle({'and':[{'resn':"GLY"},{'atom':'CA'}]},
                                {'sphere':{'colorscheme':f"WhiteCarbon",'radius':0.3}})
            view.addStyle({'and':[{'resn':"PRO"},{'atom':['C','O'],'invert':True}]},
                                {'stick':{'colorscheme':f"WhiteCarbon",'radius':0.3}})  
        if show_mainchains:
            BB = ['C','O','N','CA']
            view.addStyle({'atom':BB},{'stick':{'colorscheme':f"WhiteCarbon",'radius':0.3}})

        view.zoomTo()
    return view

show_pdb(model_num,show_sidechains, show_mainchains, color="1DDT").show()
if color == "lDDT": plot_plddt_legend().show()  
plot_confidence(model_num).show()
```

Comment: Hello @Aaron and welcome to SO, if your script is presented in your question the exact same as in your editor, it looks like the indentation level of your return statement is not properly aligned with your for loops.  Also, because of the scope of your `view` variable, it is overwritten during the course of the loops.  To directly answer your question, your are getting that error because `show_pdb` is returning `None` instead of a `py3Dmol.view`

Comment: @MaxFeinberg Thanks for your comment, Max! I've just updated my code to incorporate your advice - the function doesn't run all the way through unfortunately, but I hope my code is now more readable

Comment: Great! It looks like we're getting closer.  There is a variable, `homooligomer`, that is used before it's defined.  Is that supposed to be a parameter of the function?

Comment: @MaxFeinberg Hey Max, thanks for your comment! I don't think it's a parameter of the function but your comment prompted me to look through the original Colab and through the data that I have and I'm unfortunately not quite sure how to set it with my data

Comment: I will keep looking though and hopefully that problem can be resolved

Comment: Also, as an update, the error now is ```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'view' referenced before assignment``` and it's with the ```return``` statement in the last line of the ```show_pdb()``` function

Comment: To fix that, move the line that creates the initial view object before the for loop.

Comment: @MaxFeinberg Thanks for your comment Max! That pretty much gotten me to the finish line and I think I have some ideas about how to fix the remaining bugs - I really appreciate it Max and you've really helped me a whole lot!

Comment: I'm happy to help!  I wrote up a short answer summarizing what we've discussed.

Comment: @MaxFeinberg That's very kind of you - it really helps that you have so succinctly put it all together and I have just accepted your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view object needs to be created before the for loop so that it gets updated every cycle instead of overwriting the previous version.
So the following code

```
 for file in pdb_files:      
        view = py3Dmol.view(js='https://3dmol.org/build/3Dmol.js',)
        view.addModel(open(file,'r').read(),'pdb')
        ...
```

will look something like below.

```
 
 view = py3Dmol.view(js='https://3dmol.org/build/3Dmol.js')
 for file in pdb_files:
        view.addModel(open(file,'r').read(),'pdb')
        ...
```

And you need to assign a value to the variable `homooligomer` prior to its use later in the code.

```
 elif color == "chain":
            for n,chain,color in zip(range(homooligomer),list("ABCDEFGH"),
                             ["lime","cyan","magenta","yellow","salmon","white","blue","orange"]):
                view.setStyle({'chain':chain},{'cartoon': {'color':color}})
```